# Agora ui kit not compiling

Tags: flutter

i'm building an app on flutterflow and i've built this widget

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class VideoCall extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoCall({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  State<VideoCall> createState() => _VideoCallState();
}

class _VideoCallState extends State<VideoCall> {
  final AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
    agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
      appId: "2416802168934ee69b03279b26c91b4f",
      channelName: FFAppState().callID,
    ),
    agoraEventHandlers: AgoraRtcEventHandlers(
      onUserOffline: (connection, remoteUid, reason) => update(),
    ),
  );

  Timer? statusCheckTimer;

  // Initialize the Agora Engine
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
    startStatusCheck();
  }

  void initAgora() async {
    await client.initialize();
  }

  void startStatusCheck() {
    statusCheckTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      print("Checking status... ${FFAppState().status}");
      if (FFAppState().status == 3) {
        print("Status is 3, leaving channel...");
        timer.cancel();
        client.engine.leaveChannel();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Always cancel the timer to prevent memory leaks
    statusCheckTimer?.cancel();
    client.engine.leaveChannel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(children: [
        AgoraVideoViewer(client: client),
        AgoraVideoButtons(client: client),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

Future update() async {
  FFAppState().update(() {
    FFAppState().status = 3;
  });
}
```

yesterday, and for 2 previous weeks everything worked fine, but today i'm having this issues

```
Error: Command failed: flutter build apk --no-pub --no-version-check
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:189:7: Error: Type 'LocalVideoStreamError' not found.
LocalVideoStreamError error)? onLocalVideoStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:354:40: Error: Type 'RhythmPlayerErrorType' not found.
RhythmPlayerStateType state, RhythmPlayerErrorType errorCode)?
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:446:7: Error: Type 'LocalAudioStreamError' not found.
LocalAudioStreamError error)? onLocalAudioStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:521:7: Error: Type 'RtmpStreamPublishErrorType' not found.
RtmpStreamPublishErrorType errCode)? onRtmpStreamingStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:554:23: Error: Type 'ChannelMediaRelayEvent' not found.
final void Function(ChannelMediaRelayEvent code)? onChannelMediaRelayEvent;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:189:7: Error: 'LocalVideoStreamError' isn't a type.
LocalVideoStreamError error)? onLocalVideoStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:354:40: Error: 'RhythmPlayerErrorType' isn't a type.
RhythmPlayerStateType state, RhythmPlayerErrorType errorCode)?
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:446:7: Error: 'LocalAudioStreamError' isn't a type.
LocalAudioStreamError error)? onLocalAudioStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:521:7: Error: 'RtmpStreamPublishErrorType' isn't a type.
RtmpStreamPublishErrorType errCode)? onRtmpStreamingStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:554:23: Error: 'ChannelMediaRelayEvent' isn't a type.
final void Function(ChannelMediaRelayEvent code)? onChannelMediaRelayEvent;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/controllers/rtc_event_handlers.dart:146:6: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onChannelMediaRelayEvent'.
}, onChannelMediaRelayEvent: (code) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.3.0/lib/src/agora_rtc_engine.dart:1576:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const RtcEngineEventHandler({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and package on pub.dev is now red

I've tried changing dependecies versions, but nothing helps

dependencies - agora_uikit: ^1.3.7, agora_rtc_engine: ^6.2.2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check if all checks are there using `flutter doctor -v`

Delete the `pubspec.lock` file then run the command `flutter pub get` again.

If it still fails clear the cache of dependencies. But this process **will delete** all local packages files and **download it** once again which will take some time (depending how many package are there) - it's always better to keep the backup or use the tools like git. `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: nothing of this helped. can you please check the package? https://pub.dev/packages/agora_uikit it says [ANALYSIS ISSUE] and ERROR: The named parameter 'onChannelMediaRelayEvent' isn't defined.
ERROR: Undefined class 'LocalVideoStreamError'.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did the following and the error stopped;

1. Added this to my `build.gradule` at the Android level:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'}
       }
    }
   ```
2. Added the latest `agora_uikit` version to my `pubspec.yaml` (version 1.3.8 as of this writing).
3. Ran `flutter clean` and `flutter get`.